# Why is my container background image so zoomed in?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am having an issue with my background image of a container being zoomed in on the browser. The picture is `1200px` wide and my container is also `1200px` wide. I have it set as the background-image for my .container selector. When I load it in the browser it is only showing a small portion of the image because it is zoomed in so far. Why is this happening?

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<main role="main">
<article role="article">
<section>
<header>
<div class="container">

</div>   
</header>
</section>    
</article>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Brandon Grotesque";
  src: url("fonts/Brandon_Grotesque/Brandon_reg.otf")
  format("opentype");
}

html, body {
  padding:0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color:#222222;
}

body {
  font-family:"Brandon Grotesque";
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container {
  width: 1200px;
  height:600px;
  background-image:url("img/background.jpg");
  text-align:center;
  margin:auto;
  padding:0;
}
```

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Oh, heres another piece of it. It loads correctly in Chrome, but not in Safari! I should have tested this beforehand..... is there a webkit that I need to install for them? Thanks again!

Comment: Something in bootstrap.min.css over-riding your style.css? You can edit that bootstrap css file (probably dont want to) or add more properties in style.css to override them. Use !important in style.css properties, and if that doesn't work add inline styles, `<div class="container" style="background-image: url(img/background.jpg)">` And I see someone has answered with what some of those css properties you want to fiddle with would/could be.

Answer (score 13):

You need to specify a few more properties for your background-image like this:

```
.container {
  width: 1200px;
  height:600px;
  background-image: url("img/background.jpg");
  background-size: cover; /* or "contain" depending on what you want */
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  text-align:center;
  margin:auto;
  padding:0;
}
```

A detailed explanation of the `background` property is available in the official [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background).

Comment: I know this is an old post. But, I am not sure how this worked! Can you add a description to your answer?

Comment: @DmanCannon A link to the official MDN Web Docs has been added.

Comment: `background-size: contain` was the fix for my setup

Answer (score 1):

This works fine!

```
background:rgb(37, 16, 13) url("images/bc02.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 100%;
height:100%;
background-position: center center;
text-align:center;
margin:auto;
padding:0;
```