# Making the background image fit to window

Tags: html

When I add an image to my HTML body tag as background I got a zoomed view of the picture as background. How can I make the actual image fit to the window as the background image? I tried this but not working

```
<body background="home_back.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image" >
```

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29463586/why-is-my-background-image-so-zoomed-in) SO question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What did you try for your css?

Here's one method you can use.

```
<body background="http://images.fineartamerica.com/images-medium-large-5/3-american-bald-eagle-in-flight-michel-soucy.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">

.img-fluid {
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:100% 500px; 
}
```

The css will make the image occupy the entire screen, and make it show only once. [CSS Trick's full page bg images](https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/) might be a good read for this as well :)