# CSS: How to zoom in the background-image only slightly

Tags: html, css, background-image, css-transforms

Everything I'm looking up either talks about [animations](https://css-tricks.com/zooming-background-images/)
or [how to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29463586/why-is-my-container-background-image-so-zoomed-in) completely zoom in

**Ex.**

```css
#zoomOut {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-image: url("https://static.agcanada.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/4/2018/10/wheat-moosomin-sask-09022018-gberg.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="zoomOut">
</div>
```

or zoom out the background image.

**Ex.**

```css
#zoomIn {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-image: url("https://static.agcanada.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/4/2018/10/wheat-moosomin-sask-09022018-gberg.jpg");
    
}
```

```html
<div id="zoomIn">
</div>
```

I want the image to cover the background, but be zoomed in only a little bit.

**Ex.(Run the first snippet and view the difference in the images.)**

[image]

Comment: It can be implemented by making the background-image as a child element that fills the entire parent. Try referring this article: https://css-tricks.com/zooming-background-images/

Comment: The aspect ratio of the image also affects the zoom. For example, if the image is tall and narrow, setting it as the background-image together with the cover property will cause it to zoom in by necessity. Probably you know this, but when the image's aspect ratio is only slightly off from that of the screen, it is easy to overlook this point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My suggestion would be to attempt using the 'transform' CSS attribute.  You can then give a value of 'scale()' with a number passed into the parentheses.  The higher the number, the more the zoomed the image will appear.  The good news is that you can use decimals too.  This will allow you to zoom the image just a bit at a time. This would look a bit something like this...

```
#zoom-in {
   background-image: url("https://static.agcanada.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/4/2018/10/wheat-moosomin-sask-09022018-gberg.jpg");
   transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

You can see an example of this being done here https://css-tricks.com/zooming-background-images/